# Crash when using NDK in android but Firebase doesn't show detail log

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have added the `easyexif`, `embedIICProfile` as the C++ code into my android project.

All of them working well on my devices, but when I distribute onto the Google Play. Some crash is captured and feedback by my users but when I check on FireBase Crashlytics, it's does not show detail.

Here is my log from Firebase

```
Crashed: Thread #1
SIGABRT 0x0000000000003423
0 libc.so (Missing)
1 split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (Missing)
2 libc.so (Missing)
3 split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (Missing)
4 split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (Missing)
5 libc.so (Missing)
6 split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (Missing)
7 split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (Missing)
8 split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (Missing)
....
```

This does not show the backtrace.

Here is gradle config.

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion compileSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "easyexif"
                abiFilters = rootProject.ext.chosenAbiFilters
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared", "-DNO_TESTS=true"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters = rootProject.ext.chosenAbiFilters
        }
    }
```

```
chosenAbiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86"]
```

If someone gets the same problems, please help me. 
Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you post a full stacktrace that you get from the issue on Firebase Crashlytics? And have you made sure to follow all the basic setup instructions here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports

Comment: I have set up all of the basic instructions as this link. Here is my config, because my app has multiple native libraries, so I have built the .so files and .o file separately and then put all of files into `temp` folder. So, my config be here

Comment: Thanks for adding that extra information. From the information you've posted, your basic setup looks good, but there appears to be something stopping our plugin from properly picking up your stripped and unstripped libraries and generating symbol info. Would you mind reaching out to support@fabric.io with an issue description and a link to this post so that we can dig a bit deeper into your project? We'll circle back and update this post once we find a solution.

Comment: Yes, I will send the request to support of fabric first, thank for your advice

Answer (score -1):

My config Firebase Crashlytics

Temp folder, I have built all of the native library and get the `.so` files and `.o` files and put all of them into bellow folder

```
Project/
 /app
   /ndkout
     /libs
       /arm64-v8a
       /armeabi
       /armeabi-v7a
       /x86
       /x86-64
     /obj
       /arm64-v8a
       /armeabi
       /armeabi-v7a
       /x86
       /x86-64
```

And this is my Firebase crashlytics config

```
    crashlytics {
        enableNdk true
        androidNdkOut 'ndkout/obj'
        androidNdkLibsOut 'ndkout/libs'
    }

    // Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.0'
```

I have run the command `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` and its response successfully.

```
> Task :easyexif:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build easyexif_armeabi-v7a
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easyexif.dir/exif.cpp.o
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easyexif.dir/EasyExifJNI.cpp.o
[3/3] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mbp0015/Projects/AndroidProjects/TotalConverter/easyexif/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/libeasyexif.so
Build easyexif_arm64-v8a
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easyexif.dir/exif.cpp.o
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easyexif.dir/EasyExifJNI.cpp.o
[3/3] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mbp0015/Projects/AndroidProjects/TotalConverter/easyexif/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libeasyexif.so
Build easyexif_x86
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easyexif.dir/exif.cpp.o
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/easyexif.dir/EasyExifJNI.cpp.o
[3/3] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mbp0015/Projects/AndroidProjects/TotalConverter/easyexif/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libeasyexif.so

> Task :embedIICProfile:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build embedICCProfile_armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedICCProfile.dir/EmbedICCProfile.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mbp0015/Projects/AndroidProjects/TotalConverter/embedIICProfile/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/libembedICCProfile.so
Build embedICCProfile_arm64-v8a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedICCProfile.dir/EmbedICCProfile.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mbp0015/Projects/AndroidProjects/TotalConverter/embedIICProfile/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libembedICCProfile.so
Build embedICCProfile_x86
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedICCProfile.dir/EmbedICCProfile.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mbp0015/Projects/AndroidProjects/TotalConverter/embedIICProfile/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libembedICCProfile.so

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 18s
109 actionable tasks: 23 executed, 86 up-to-date
```

All right, so my Firebase Crashltics log still does not show.
The different thing is I'm using an android app bundle for upload into Google console instead `apk` file.

The log does not show more detail.

```
Crashed: Thread #1
SIGABRT 0x000027f700004b0c
0
libc.so
(Missing)
1
libc.so
(Missing)
2
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
3
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
4
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
5
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
6
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
7
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
8
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
9
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
10
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
11
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
12
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
(Missing)
13
base.odex
(Missing)
14
libart.so
(Missing)
15
libc.so
(Missing)
16
libutils.so
(Missing)
17
libutils.so
(Missing)
18
libandroid_runtime.so
(Missing)
19
(Missing)
20
(Missing)
21
(Missing)
22
(Missing)
23
(Missing)
24
boot-framework.oat
(Missing)
25
(Missing)
26
(Missing)
27
(Missing)
28
(Missing)
29
(Missing)
30
(Missing)
31
boot-framework.oat
(Missing)
32
(Missing)
33
(Missing)
34
(Missing)
35
(Missing)
36
(Missing)
37
(Missing)
38
(Missing)
39
(Missing)
40
(Missing)
41
(Missing)
42
(Missing)
43
boot-framework.oat
(Missing)
44
(Missing)
45
(Missing)
46
(Missing)
47
libart.so
(Missing)
48
(Missing)
49
(Missing)
50
libart.so
(Missing)
51
(Missing)
52
(Missing)
53
(Missing)
54
(Missing)
55
(Missing)
56
(Missing)
57
(Missing)
58
(Missing)
59
(Missing)
60
libart.so
(Missing)
61
(Missing)
62
(Missing)
63
(Missing)
64
(Missing)
```